# Echofish Error 500 "CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection"

Tags: php, centos, mariadb

I have to test [Echofish](https://echothrust.github.io/echofish/) to centralize log files.

I followed the installation procedure , but this one does not seem up to date.

When that connects me to the web interface , I get an error 500 - "CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection."

[Error 500 in Echofish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh5lm.png)

When manually connects me to the database with " mysql -u echofish -p ETS_echofish ", it's works.

I changed the file db.php following documentation.

```
    <?php
return array(
                        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=ETS_echofish',
                        'emulatePrepare' => true,
                        'username' => 'echofish',
                        'password' => 'my_password',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                );
```

I use CentOS 7
Echofish uses Yii

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php
return array(
                        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=ETS_echofish',
                        'emulatePrepare' => false,
                        'username' => 'echofish',
                        'password' => 'my_password',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                );
```

Comment: What does `emulatePrepare` mean?

Comment: PDO library with strings instead of on the MySQL server using the binary protocol

Comment: Hello,

I just replaced the argument true to false.
I restart services.
I still have the same 500 error

Thanks

Comment: please check connection port. please share your website url

Comment: 3306 does not appear when I go to a netstat. The problem would come of it you there ??

Mysql process is present.

Comment: I have no site address, as this is in testing. It will be for local use.
The database and Echofish are on the same machine

Comment: 'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=yourdatabase',
    'username' => 'your user name ',
    'password' => 'your password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',

Comment: Hello,
I solved the problem by disabling SELinux with : / usr / sbin / setenforce 0

Answer (score 0):

Found the following solution which avoided disabling SELinux: [Connect DATABASE Error TYPE: 2002: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178774/connect-database-error-type-2002-permission-denied)

Basicly `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

That solved my problem. Hope it helps.