# Connect DATABASE Error TYPE: 2002: Permission denied

Tags: php, mysql, curl, selinux

I am trying to connect the database with the following script(cxn-test.php)

```
<?php
$host = '155.30.136.20';//dummy ip 
$user = 'abc_user';
$pass = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$dbname = 'welcome';
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$dbname);
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}else {
    echo "success" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

When I am trying on the terminal

> php cxn-test.php //success

But when I am trying on localhost i am getting the following error,

> curl -s http://localhost/cxn-test.php

`Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.
Debugging errno: 2002
Debugging error: Permission denied`

This is strange issue it's not working on the localhost but working good on command line.

Comment: Where is the database located? is it in a Docker container? Have you tried `mysqli` or PDO mysql?

Comment: it's located in another server i am connecting remotely using ip

Comment: when accessing it via the command line, are you ssh'd in to the remote server, or the same computer as the one running the localhost?

Comment: remote server only

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had the same issue after getting a new CentOS 7 box, running SELinux. I could connect to my remote MySQL DB server from the command line, but Drupal (and test PHP scripts) could not.

The issue turned out to be the SELinux security policies.

By default, the policy **httpd_can_network_connect_db** is disabled (meaning that your web server *cannot* contact a remote DB.)

Check this via:

`getsebool -a | grep httpd`

If  httpd_can_network_connect_db is Off, enable it via:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

(The -P flag makes the change permanent, so the setting survives a reboot.)

Comment: Nice, +1 for not telling people to turn off SELinux!

Comment: I had same issue which only got fixed by disabling SELinux. Thanks for your comment for highlighting it

Comment: Work like a charm. Kudos to you.

Comment: Took me FOREVER to find this (using Redhat).  Thank you so much.

Comment: For anyone trying to connect remotely from a Digital Ocean droplet to an AWS instance, this was necessary on the droplet in addition to these steps on the instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766014/connect-to-mysql-on-amazon-ec2-from-a-remote-server